# Is there a python GIL in Flask?

Tags: python, multithreading, flask

I am studying python multiple thread recently, and I found that GIL will force python to run a single thread at one time even on a multi-core CPUs.

So I did some little PoC.

My code is following :

```
import threading
import time

COUNT = 50000000
def count():
    i = 0
    print('thread id =', threading.get_ident())
    while(i < COUNT):
        i = i +1

start_time = time.time()
count()
count()
end_time = time.time()
print(f'execution time without multiple threading : {end_time - start_time}')

start_time = time.time()
t_1 = threading.Thread(target=count)
t_2 = threading.Thread(target=count)
t_1.start()
t_2.start()
t_1.join()
t_2.join()
end_time = time.time()
print(f'execution time with multiple threading : {end_time - start_time}')
```

And this is my result:

```
thread id = 2204
thread id = 2204
execution time without multiple threading : 5.695769786834717
thread id = 3492
thread id = 5260
execution time with multiple threading : 5.339878082275391
```

This is very clearly how GIL works.

But now I am doing the same process on Flask
and it seems like GIL doesn't work as expected.
this is my code :

**server.py**

```
from flask import Flask
import threading
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
COUNT = 50000000

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    print ('Thread id = ', threading.get_ident())
    print ('Process id = ', os.getpid())
    i = 0
    while(i < COUNT):
        i = i +1
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**client.py**

```
import requests
import time
import multiprocessing as mp

def send():
    start_time = time.time()
    r = requests.get('http://localhost:5000')
    end_time = time.time()
    print(f'response after {end_time - start_time}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p_1 = mp.Process(target=send)
    p_2 = mp.Process(target=send)
    p_1.start()
    p_2.start()
    p_1.join()
    p_2.join()
```

result of server.py:

```
Thread id =  18428
Process id =  19000
Thread id =  17436
Process id =  19000
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Sep/2020 09:36:19] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Sep/2020 09:36:19] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

result of client.py

```
response after 7.361770153045654
response after 7.373677015304565
```

It seems like 2 client get responses at the same time, but with GIL, my expected result should be
7.3 first response and 14.xxx in second response. Can any one help me to verify this issue ?

Comment: Odds are flask (or whatever you're running flask under) is forking new processes to service requests. The GIL hurts threads, but independent processes are unaffected.

Comment: The GIL does not block threads forever. It is still possible that two threads seems to run at the same time but are actually quickly switching control.

Comment: @KlausD.: Not in this case; the delay here is entirely a CPU-bound loop (not a blocking task where one could do work while the other is blocked). The work done by each thread cannot be done at the same time, and they have to pay the cost of context switches on top of that each time control is switched. If the work was a `time.sleep(7)` or something, it could work as you describe, but if a single thread would take 7 seconds on purely CPU-bound work, adding another thread doing that same work again will roughly double the time.

Comment: Uhg.. mobile scrolling fail.

Comment: Hi @ShadowRanger Thanks for your reply, but I already print the process id and thread id, and the process id are same but thread is not, it seems like they are running in a same process...

Comment: @EnergyBoy: Good point, missed that. Not sure how this would work; I think the only modern-ish Python interpreters are CPython and PyPy, both of which are GIL-bound. Perhaps some timeout such that the connection closes before the loops finish (all your `print`s precede the loop)? Maybe try adding `print`s after the loop and see if they appear in the client's output?

Comment: @ShadowRanger OK I will test that BTW this is a really interesting problem haha

Comment: @EnergyBoy: It occurs to me that the `print`s are all local to the server; to confirm the connection isn't closed, you'd probably need to `print` the server's response on the client side.

Comment: @ShadowRanger how can I implement it ?

Comment: @ShadowRanger I think I just find the answer, I try to send a request just one time and it takes the half time, so it means GIL really does work on Flask too!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a GIL in Python Flask too
In the question I asked, I didn't send a request singly to the server.
Actually it takes half of time to get response for a singly request.
And why can we get two responses at the same time ? It's because there are sys.getswitchinterval() in it so the threads will be switched out every 0.005 sec until they finished the job.

Answer (score -1):

As pointed out by @ShadowRanger in the comments, the central tenet behind this answer (namely that two processes are counting down the same variable and thread local storage is needed) is incorrect. I will, however, leave the answer as it does contain some information that was useful to the OP in finding a solution.

Using the GIL, the Python interpreter does indeed only allow one thread to run at a time - apart from I/O operations. It has a *"switch interval"* which is how often it stops running one thread and takes a look at running another thread for a while. You can check it with:

```
sys.getswitchinterval()
```

and it is set to 5ms on my system.

What you are seeing is two threads, both of which are running for around 5ms at a time but both are incrementing the **same** variable because you have a shared address space with threads. So there are not 2 threads each counting to 50000000, there are two threads each counting down part of a single 50000000.

What you need is *"thread-local storage"* so each increments its own counter:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from flask import Flask
import threading
import os, sys

app = Flask(__name__)
COUNT = 50000000

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    print ('Thread id = ', threading.get_ident())
    print ('Process id = ', os.getpid())
    mydata = threading.local()
    mydata.i = 0
    while(mydata.i < COUNT):
        mydata.i = mydata.i +1
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == '__main__':

    print(f'switch interval: {sys.getswitchinterval()}')
    app.run()
```

If I run your original code, I get:

```
response after 5.990185022354126
response after 6.009223937988281
```

If I run my code with `i` in thread-local storage, I get:

```
response after 19.429346084594727 
response after 19.553659200668335
```

Comment: That doesn't explain it; `i` is a local variable to the function, not a global, so it's not shared between threads. Only `COUNT` is global/shared, and it's never mutated.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thank you for your thoughts. I'll leave it as it is for the minute (rather than deleting it) as the actual answer may be related and my answer might jog someone's ideas about possible causes.

Comment: Hi @MarkSetchell Thanks for your help! interval time really help me to clarify my thought